# I suddenly get this error after one day "Attempted import error: 'CombineReducdrs' is not exported from 'redux'."

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import authReducer from './authReducer'
import projectReducer from './projectReducer'
import {CombineReducdrs} from 'redux';

const rootReducer = CombineReducdrs({
    auth : authReducer,
    project : projectReducer
});

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Would it be just that `CombineReducdrs` has a typo in it ? It's `CombineReducers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) not CombineReducdrs!

Comment: yea it was such a sham :) i got that